# HybridAuth Facebook, Twitter and Google failure

Tags: hybridauth

I was able to connect to Social account the the HybridAuth library, and it stopped working when migrating all files from one server to another.the same app id works well in existing server.

#### What I have tried:

- Resetting my facebok, Twitter app access tokens
- Creating an All new Facebook, Twitter app
- Using the HybridAuth debug mode to troubleshoot

#### The error message:

> Authentification failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.

- Original error message: `Authentification failed! Twitter returned an error. 401 Unauthorized.`
- Original error message: `Authentification failed! Facebook returned an error. 401 Unauthorized.`
- Original error message: `Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.`

#### Trace:

```
#0 /home/www/../hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php(39): Hybrid_Auth::initialize('/home/www/molid...')
#1 /home/www/../hybridauth/authenticate/social_hub/login.php(22): Hybrid_Auth->__construct('/home/www/molid...')
#2 {main}
```

I found some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594503/hybridauth-twitter-failure-401), but I can't set server time,

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I have find solution for that and its work for me.

Please change the `https` with http in `api_base_url` in provider folder according to your social media file.

It may help you.